# Singular Values

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and denote the singular values of $A$ by $\sigma_1 \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_n$. Prove that 
$$\sigma_k = \underset{dim W = n-k+1}{\min} \underset{u \in W, ||u|| = 1}{\max}||Au||$$

I don't know how to start this proof. Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are we allowed to assume the [min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem)?

Comment: You can start by exploring the $n=2$ case:  Any complex $2\times 2$ matrix has an eigenvalue, so that's one of the $\sigma$s.  Then try to figure out how the other $\sigma$ relates to the formula you have.

Comment: Yes, we are allowed to use the min-max theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $\|Au\|^2 = u^T(A^TA)u$, and that $A^TA$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

First note that 
$$||Au||^2 = (Au)^*(Au) = u^*A^*Au$$
From the above, it is clear that $A^*A$ is Hermitian. Then, by Courant-Fischer Theorem, we have that 
$$\lambda_k = \underset{dim W = n-k+1}{\min} \underset{u \in W, ||u|| = 1}{\max} u^*A^*Au$$
where $\lambda_k$ is the $k$th eigenvalue of $A^*A$. Recall, the singular values of a matrix $A$ are the square root of the eigenvalues of $A^*A$. Thus, using the above result, we have that
$$\sigma_k = \sqrt{\lambda_k} = \underset{dim W = n-k+1}{\min} \underset{u \in W, ||u|| = 1}{\max} \sqrt{u^*A^*Au}$$
Thus
$$\sigma_k = \underset{dim W = n-k+1}{\min} \underset{u \in W, ||u|| = 1}{\max} \sqrt{u^*A^*Au} = \underset{dim W = n-k+1}{\min} \underset{u \in W, ||u|| = 1}{\max} ||Au||$$
as desired.